# Wordpress site reverted from https... links broken

Tags: wordpress, ssl, redirect

A site new to me as of today is broken. It is a wordpress site that the client tried to convert to HTTPS by themselves and it broke. They then tried to undo the work and go back to non-s version.

this has worked with one exception. The site is trying to redirect scripts to the SSL version.

For example trying to access this:

`http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4`
is redirecting to this:
`https://www.example.com/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4`

(not the real domain.. obv)

Can anybody advise on how to fully revert?

If it helps, the Security Cert was purchase through Namecheap. The hosting is GoDaddy, and they attempted to follow the instructions here: https://designmodo.com/wordpress-https/

** edit **

SSL has been reinstalled, and it doesn't appear to be the problem. Something is redirecting scripts, removing the "wp-includes" from the url

the htaccess

```
# BEGIN GD-SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
</IfModule>
# END GD-SSL

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Restore from backup and install the [Really Simple SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/)

Comment: if there were backups that'd be great advice :/ this site came to me AFTER it was broken

Comment: Would you mind to share the content of your .htaccess here?

Comment: sure, I'll edit the post (too long for here)

Comment: Try to remove all between the `# BEGIN GD-SSL` and  `# END GD-SSL`

Comment: if I do that won't it just kill the secure site? (plus I know for sure it was doing the weird redirect before that was in the htaccess)

Comment: It will, but your next step will be installing the plugin I mentioned before in my first comment.

Comment: ok, I removed code from the .htaccess and installed Really Simple SSL... It's still redirecting incorrectly

Comment: Have you tried in different browses?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress save a lot of content and settings in the database, try installing this plugin [Velvet Blues Update URLs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) to find-replace in your database the old values `https://example.com` with `http://example.com` some plugins save their own cache, so you probably need to go into a file browser and delete their cache folders.

If that doesn't work double check that your `.htaccess` is not redirecting your http traffic to https.

Comment: so the SSL portion of the problem isn't what's actually wrong. Something is removing "/wp-includes/" from the urls... I'm not sure how to search for the lack of something with velvet blues.